# Configurations to run multiple microservices in single micronaut Project

Tags: java, grails, microservices, micronaut

I have converted multiple backend services from grails to microservices in single micronaut project and want to run all those microserservices on different ports simultaneously.
Which configurations i must have to do to achieve this scenario.

Comment: looks like a natural use case for vert.x framework

Comment: Are you wanting the multiple services to be separate processes?

Comment: I have added multiple microservices in single micronaut project. And wanted to run all of them at a time on different ports.

Comment: @iUbaid Understood.  You said that in the original question.  I am asking if you want them to be separate processes.  Having multiple services within a process listening on different ports requires a different solution than having multiple services in separate processes listening on different ports.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only created a single Micronaut application then everything is available on the same port. 
To run every microservice on different ports you can create a Gradle/Maven multi-project build and split the single application into those projects, so they are independent from each other.

Comment: We write our configuration for single microservice in application.yml. can you please provide any example that explains same for multiple microservices

Comment: In https://guides.micronaut.io/ there are a lot of guides that have multiple microservices, for example: https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-microservices-services-discover-consul/guide/index.html